# Substituting require and module.exports for ES6 import export

Tags: node.js, express

A lot of online documentations use the commonjs commands `require` and `module.exports`. I've learned everything with ES6's `import` and `export` and I'm using them in all projects.

I'm not quite sure whether I messed up something in my app.js or the route file but I seem to be unable to route from external source.

This is my `app.js` route loading:

```
import {router as toolsRoute} from './routes/tools.js'
app.use('/tools,', toolsRoute)
```

And this is my `/routes/tools.js`

```
import express from 'express'

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req,res) => res.send('tools'))

export { router }
```

I'm testing it on localhost and right now I can reach `localhost:3000/` but can't reach `localhost:3000/tools`.

What am I missing here? Wronge use of the keywords or something with the importing?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in your modules exports, it's correct. I see the problem in the path you are processing. Path does not work as folders. **You have to always evaluate whole path.**
Even if your route is catched in `app.use('/tools',...)` in the router, it is again evaluated to whole path. The parameter according to Express documentation is path, not a substring of it. (https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use)
It means, correct approach:

```
// app.js
app.use('/tools', toolsRoute)

// routes/tools.js
router.get('/tools', (req,res) => res.send('tools'))
```

But you will not catch eg `/tools/example` path in your router, because there is no specified path in app.js.

So more common, how routers are used is:
`app.use('/', toolsRoute)`

Or, if you really want to have /tools in your router path, then this way:
`app.use('/tools/*', toolsRoute)`
So or so, you have to always specify full path in the router itself.

And one small mistake, you have colon after tools in app.use.